# NodeJS - Error: write EPIPE on SOCKS5 proxy

Tags: node.js, sockets, proxy, socks

I get the following stacktrace when trying to make `net.Socket()` connection to a SOCKS5-server:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:769:14)
```

My code is as follows:

```
var net = require('net');

var proxy = {
    host: '115.159.155.96',
    port: 1080,
    dstHost: 'www.google.com',
    dstPort: 80
};

var socket = new net.connect({
    host: proxy.host,
    port: proxy.port
}, function() {
    console.log('connected!');

    var addrlen = Buffer.byteLength(proxy.dstHost);
    var reqbuf = new Buffer(7 + addrlen);
    var p;

    reqbuf[0] = 0x05;
    reqbuf[1] = 0x01;
    reqbuf[2] = 0x00;
    reqbuf[3] = 0x03;
    reqbuf[4] = addrlen;
    reqbuf.write(proxy.dstHost, 5, addrlen);
    p = 5 + addrlen;

    reqbuf.writeUInt16BE(proxy.dstPort, p, true);
    socket.write(reqbuf);

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        if(data.toString('hex') == '0500') { // This means 0x05 for version 5 and 0x00 for 'succeeded', right?
            var bfr = new Buffer('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com');
            socket.write(bfr);
            // I also tried "socket.write('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com');",
            // but I got the same error.
        }

        console.log(data.toString());
    });
});
```

I'm sure this is not the right way to do a connection to the socket. What would be the correct method to do it?

I took the code above out of `lib/client.js` in the [socksv5](https://github.com/mscdex/socksv5/) package.

By the way, I do not want to use an existing package (I know there are lots of SOCKS-Client packages for NodeJS), because I would like to learn SOCKS by doing it.

**Edit:** Here is the output of `curl -vv --socks5-hostname 115.159.155.96:1080 http://api.ipify.org?format=json`, like Quedaro suggested below:

```
root@mymachine:~# curl -vv --socks5-hostname 115.159.155.96:1080
http://api.ipify.org?format=json
* Rebuilt URL to: http://api.ipify.org/?format=json
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 115.159.155.96...
* Connected to 115.159.155.96 (115.159.155.96) port 1080 (#0)
> GET /?format=json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: api.ipify.org
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Cowboy is not blacklisted
< Server: Cowboy
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 18:15:59 GMT
< Content-Length: 23
< Via: 1.1 vegur
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.ipify.org left intact
{"ip":"115.159.155.96"}
root@mymachine:~#
```

This means, that the proxy should work fine, doesn't it?

I also added an error-event to the socket, simply logging `err` to console. This is, what I get:

```
{ [Error: write EPIPE] code: 'EPIPE', errno: 'EPIPE', syscall: 'write' }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the working code here if someone stumbles upon this question.

As @Quedaro had mentioned, the socks5 handshake was missing.

```
var net = require('net');

var proxy = {
  host: 'localhost', // You can create a socks5 server by running `ssh -D 8001 xyz.com`
  port: 8001,
  destinationHost: 'www.google.com',
  destinationPort: 80,
  destinationPath: '/'
};

var socks5Handshake = new Buffer(3);
socks5Handshake[0] = 0x05; // SOCKS version number (must be 0x05 for this version)
socks5Handshake[1] = 0x01; // Number of authentication methods supported.
socks5Handshake[2] = 0x00; // 0x00: No authentication

var serverHandshakeResponse = "0500"; // SOCKS version number followed by chosen authentication method, 1 byte, or 0xFF if no acceptable methods were offered.
var serverConnectionResponse = "05000001000000000000";

var socket = new net.connect({
  host: proxy.host,
  port: proxy.port
}, function() {
  // Socket connect done. Initiating Socks5 handshake
  socket.write(socks5Handshake);

  // Error event handler to handle error in case of ECONNRESET, ECONNREFUSED etc.
  socket.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('error!', err);
  });

  socket.once('data', function(data) {
    if(data.toString('hex') == serverHandshakeResponse) {
      var addressLength = Buffer.byteLength(proxy.destinationHost);
      var requestBuffer = new Buffer(7 + addressLength);
      var portOffset;

      requestBuffer[0] = 0x05; // SOCKS version number (must be 0x05 for this version)
      requestBuffer[1] = 0x01; // establish a TCP/IP stream connection
      requestBuffer[2] = 0x00; // reserved, must be 0x00
      requestBuffer[3] = 0x03; // address type, 1 byte. 0x03 = Domain name
      requestBuffer[4] = addressLength; // 1 byte of name length followed by the name for domain name
      requestBuffer.write(proxy.destinationHost, 5, addressLength);
      portOffset = 5 + addressLength;

      requestBuffer.writeUInt16BE(proxy.destinationPort, portOffset, true);
      socket.write(requestBuffer);
      socket.once('data', function(data){
        if(data.toString('hex') == serverConnectionResponse) {
          var requestBuffer = new Buffer("GET " + proxy.destinationPath + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + proxy.destinationHost + ":" + proxy.destinationPort + "\r\n\r\n");
          socket.write(requestBuffer);
          socket.once('data', function(data){
            console.log("Response for the url:", proxy.destinationHost + ":" + proxy.destinationPort, "=>", data.toString().match(/^HTTP\/1\.. \d+/i)[0]);
            socket.end();
          });
        }
        else {
          console.log("Socks5 connection request failed. Closing the socket");
          socket.end();
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log("Socks5 handshake failed. Closing the socket");
      socket.end();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that socks server actually works? Write `EPIPE` means the socket cannot be written because the connection had been dropped, hopefully closed by the server. Try it testing this command (on Linux systems):

```
curl -vv --socks5-hostname 115.159.155.96:1080 http://api.ipify.org?format=json
```

Also, before sending that data you may want to say 'hello' to the socks server, like sending these bytes: `0x05 0x02 0x00 0x01`

To don't get thrown on any socket exception, try to capture the `'error'` event, like this:

```
socket.on('error', function(err){        
    console.log('error!', err);
});
```

Comment: I edited my question and added the information :) Thanks for your reply.